# lampp wait until external sources are loaded

Tags: php, load, lampp

I have a PHP web page which should use external images (they are displayed in the page) and get the text from an external source that is then used by a JavaScript script.

When I was using xampp in Windows, I had no problem and the content was displayed as expected.

When using lampp, it seems that the content is displayed before it has finished loading/processing.

Is there any setting or other means to force waiting until everything is ready?

Comment: That external server latency is same as before? And your internet speed is same as before?

Comment: Yes; the sources used are the same and I parallelly checked xampp and lampp. Every time, the result is the same.

Comment: what do you mean `content is displayed before it has finished loading/processing`? it does not display the correct data?

Comment: I mean that the non-external content along with the external content that happens to be ready are displayed. In example, an image url can be correct but the image in not displayed.

Comment: Can you check console and network tabs and confirm everything fine?

Comment: Yes, they seem OK.

Comment: You said `image url can be correct but the image in not displayed` what is the network responses for those images?

Answer (score 0):

What content is displayed before loading is finished?

It is normal that the page loads and maybe it will take longer time to display the images dependig on your connection, or the server speed of the external source...

If content is processed from your Java Script before the page is completly loaded you maybe do not have put all Scripts at the bottom of your page or not surrounded the code with a "document.onload" or "window.onload" function, which may cause JS errors!

Comment: I use PHP to form the url of each image that is "echo-ed" and JavaScript functions that when they are called they get text from an external source and display it with some formatting. Non-external content along with the external content that happens to be ready are displayed. Before all the expected content is loaded there is no indication of loading in the browser.

Comment: I think I don't get the question right...
Is everything loaded but some things too early or too late,
or are not all things loaded correctly!?